# Python Regex - Making an exception involving two text files

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have two text files: text1 and text2.

text1:

```
(test1)
(test2)
(g)
(test3)
(test4)
(test5)
```

text2:

```
(test5)
(testa)
(testb)
(testc)
(testd)
(teste)
```

And I have the following code:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(\((?!test2:|g}|test4)[\w+ :]+\))")
with open("text2.txt", "r") as f:
    words = pattern.findall(f.read())

with open("text1.txt", "r+") as f:
    content = pattern.sub(lambda x: words.pop(0) if words else x.group(), f.read())
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(content)
    f.truncate()
```

What this code does is, by using regular expression, changing the words inside the parenthesis in test1.txt one by one, in order, with the words inside the parenthesis in test2.txt, with some exceptions with "test2", "test4" an the letter "g". However, I want to make another exception: if, for example, (test5) appears in both files, even if it's in different lines, it won't be slected by re, so it won't be replaced; leaving text1.txt like this:

```
(testa)
(test2)
(g)
(testb)
(test4)
(test5)
```

My question is: how should I do this? Should I change the logic of my program? Or should I just change the RE?

Comment: Your pattern doesnt seem to work properly. It is still replacing (g) and (test2).

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside some errors in the pattern you posted (I don't figure how this works for you with given example), with regard to the strategy, you can add all exceptions to a list, and once iterated over both files, append new exceptions (occurrences in both files) and compile the regex expression by inserting into it all of the them (exceptions) joining by '|' character.

This code works for me .

```
import re

exceptions=['test2','test4','g']
pattern1 = re.compile(r"(\((?!"+'|'.join(ex for ex in exceptions)+")[\w+ :]+\))")

with open("text2.txt", "r") as f:
    words = pattern1.findall(f.read())
    print(words)

with open("text1.txt", "r+") as f:
    text = f.read()
    for line in text.splitlines():
        if line in words:
            new_exception =  re.search(r'\(([\w+ :]+)\)',line)
            exceptions.append(new_exception.group(1))
            words.remove(line)

    all_exceptions_compiled = re.compile(r"(\((?!"+'|'.join(ex for ex in exceptions)+")[\w+ :]+\))")
    content = all_exceptions_compiled.sub(lambda x: words.pop(0) if words else x.group(), text)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(content)
    f.truncate()
```

Keep in mind that I have modified your regex pattern by: `(\((?!test2|g|test4)[\w+ :]+\))`

This code implements a iteration (On) and a deletion (On) operations over a list which, depending on the size of n, can not be an efficient solution. You should improve this part if the performance is an element to consider.

Comment: Thank you so, so much. That was perfect.

Comment: @legXen feel free to mark the answer as correct if this is so.